# How to transform JSON to another JSON by using XSLT

Tags: json, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I have to take the input as JSON and transform it to another JSON by using XSLT.

Input JSON:

```js
{
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man1",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes"
    },
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man2",
      "age": 30,
      "secretIdentity": "Martin"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert the above JSON to look like this:

```js
{
   "resourceType": "Test",
   "type": {
      "name": "Member"
   },
   "displayName": "Molecule Man",
   "attributes": {
      "test": [
         {
            "value": "29"
         }
      ],
      "testing": [
         {
            "value": "Dan Jukes"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have tried with the below code and am not able to get the desired output JSON. I am getting an error **SERE0023  JSON serialization: cannot handle a sequence of length 2** and also getting the error as **saxon:array is not recognized as** **Saxon instruction.Saxon extensions require Saxon-PE or higher,** while trying to implement **<saxon::array> .**

I have used Saxon HE(12.0) dependency.

**Java Code**

```
package com.practice;

import net.sf.saxon.s9api.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class JsonToXsltToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, SaxonApiException {
        Processor processor = new Processor(false);
        TransformJson(processor);
    }

    static void TransformJson(Processor processor) throws 
 FileNotFoundException, SaxonApiException {
       
        JsonBuilder jsonBuilder = processor.newJsonBuilder();
        XdmValue input = jsonBuilder.parseJson(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
        XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File("jsonTransform.xsl")));
        Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable.load30();
        xslt30Transformer.applyTemplates(input, xslt30Transformer.newSerializer(System.out));

    }
}
```

`sample.xsl`:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
                xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:param name="nodes" as="map(*)*"/>

    <xsl:template name="init">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="($nodes)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template  match=".">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'resourceType'" select="'Test'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'type'">
            <xsl:map-entry key="'name'" select="'Member'"/>
            </xsl:map-entry>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'displayName'" select= "?members?1?name"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'attributes'">
            <xsl:map-entry key="'age'">
            <xsl:map-entry key="'value'" select="?members?1?age"/>
            </xsl:map-entry>
                <xsl:map-entry key="'secretIdentity'">
                    <xsl:map-entry key="'value'" select="?members?1?secretIdentity"/>
                </xsl:map-entry>
            </xsl:map-entry>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```
````

Comment: Please add the Java code to run the XSLT so that we see where/how you pass the JSON to the XSLT.

Comment: The error tells you that you have a sequence of two items as the value of a map, that is not possible in JSON. To see the result your current code produces you can switch to `method="adaptive"` for testing/debugging. Then you see that `attributes` as its value has a sequence of maps.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this all in XPath:

```
<xsl:sequence select="
  map{'resourceType':'Test',
      'type':map{'name':'Member'},
      'displayName': ?members?1?name,
      'attributes': map{
          'test': [?members?1?age],
          'testing': [?members?1?secretIdentity]}
     }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a nested map:

```
    <xsl:map>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'resourceType'" select="'Test'"/>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'type'">
          <xsl:map-entry key="'name'" select="'Member'"/>
        </xsl:map-entry>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'displayName'" select= "?members?1?name"/>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'attributes'">
          <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'test'" select="[?members?1?age]"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'testing'" select="[?members?1?secretIdentity]"/>
          </xsl:map>
        </xsl:map-entry>
    </xsl:map>
```

And for

```
        <xsl:map-entry key="'test'" select="[?members?1?age]"/>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'testing'" select="[?members?1?secretIdentity]"/>
```

you might

```
        <xsl:map-entry key="'test'" select="[map { 'value' : ?members?1?age }]"/>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'testing'" select="[map { 'value' : ?members?1?secretIdentity }]"/>
```

Comment: Here test will be an array. Inside that "value":29 is there. I am stuck there. For this I have applied <Saxon:array>. But it didn't work.

Comment: @RamPrasad, see whether the edit or of course Michael Kay's answer helps. If you want to use `saxon:array` you need to use EE (or perhaps PE) with a license, Saxonica tends to hand out trial licenses for new customers.